# Creating many line plots using positions as function as time

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, scientific-computing

I am trying to make a single plot of the trajectory of many particles from a Brownian Motion experiment.
There are five measurements for each particle, a total of 10, for the x and y components of position.

I have the data in multiple data structures, as I am unaware of which is most useful for the end I aim to achieve. 
1. All within a single data frame, with my 5 time measurements in x for the 16 particles measured, followed by the 16 for the y component.

[Single data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZBF5.png)

2. In two separate dataframes, one for the x-component and one for the y.

I have tried to use rbind to create a single array that I can use geom_line() but this means I have one single line where each particle trajectory is connected to one another.

How could I go about making these different lines, all within one x-y plane. Thanks

Comment: Please don't share data using images. Include a sample of your data using `dput()`, and we'll be better position to help out.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to have 3 columns, one for the common x component, one for the y, and one for the particle. To get this you'll need to convert your data to long format:

```
> df <- data.frame(t=c(1,2,3,4,5), x.1 = c(-1,1,3,4,5), x.2 = c(5,2,1,4,6))
> df
  t x.1 x.2
1 1  -1   5
2 2   1   2
3 3   3   1
4 4   4   4
5 5   5   6
> (df <- tidyr::gather(df, "particle", "y", -t))
   t particle  y
1  1      x.1 -1
2  2      x.1  1
3  3      x.1  3
4  4      x.1  4
5  5      x.1  5
6  1      x.2  5
7  2      x.2  2
8  3      x.2  1
9  4      x.2  4
10 5      x.2  6
```

Then, use the `group` parameter to `geom_line` to plot them separately:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = y)) + geom_line(aes(group = particle, color = particle))
```

Comment: It sounded like the OP wants them all connected--maybe `geom_step` would be useful here?

Comment: You can't use geom line because it does not consider the time. It first orders the X values from min to max and then plots in that order.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to have your data in this format

```
data <- data.table(particle = as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 5)),
                   x = sample(-10:10, 15, replace = TRUE),
                   y = sample(-10:10, 15, replace = TRUE))
data

    particle   x   y
 1:        1  -8  -4
 2:        1  -5  -2
 3:        1  -1  -5
 4:        1  -3   9
 5:        1   4  -7
 6:        2   2   1
 7:        2  -8 -10
 8:        2  -4  -8
 9:        2  -6  -4
10:        2  -8  -3
11:        3 -10  10
12:        3   6  -5
13:        3  -5  -6
14:        3  -6   8
15:        3   1  -4
```

One column for identifying the particle and the other for the position in coordinates.

This link might help you changing your data: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

Then just plot grouping by particle (using `color` aes)

```
ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = x, y = y, color = particle)) +
  geom_path(size = 3)
```

[image]

If you want to change the order of the path, just add a column of time and sort the df by that column.